# Better organization of NGXS state

Tags: angular, ngxs

i have a state that is rather complex (here is the defaults section to see how nested it is), and my number of actions is quite big so the file goes to around 500 loc. Not sure what the best practice is for a better organization of it. Not sure if using child states (if possible to use) would make things better.

```
name: 'exhibition',
defaults: {
    loading: false,
    editable: false,
    selectedPage: 1,
    selectedLanguage: 'Language',
    selectedSection: 0,
    id: 0,
    title: 'Some title',
    thumbnail: 'assets/images/thumbnail/placeholder-thumbnail.png',
    create_date: new Date(),
    note: 'Note',
    published: false,
    pages: [
        {
            introductory: false,
            background_color: '#fae7cc',
            page_number: 1,
            row_number: 20,
            column_number: 20,
            language: 'Language',
            sections: [
                {
                    section_order: 1,
                    x_coordinate: 1,
                    y_coordinate: 1,
                    width: 20,
                    height: 20,
                    content: {
                        text_content: '<p>insert in some text</p>',
                        content_type: 'text',
                        file: {
                            name: '',
                            file: '',
                            file_type: ''
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to consider to create stores side by side by using [composition](https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/composition)